# python class objects not drawing graphics window

Tags: python, graphics

I don't understand why the following code will not construct a graphics window with the circle. It does construct an object, but not graphically, when I run `SomeObject = Tracker()`

Why is that? This is a simple snippet of code, just for me to understand why I'm not getting a graphics window.

```
# tracker.py
from graphics import *

class Tracker:

    def __inti__(self):

        self.win = GraphWin('tracker', 500, 500)
        self.circle = Circle(Point(0, 0), 0.5)
        self.circle.draw(self.win)
```

Comment: For one, it should be `__init__`.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, but it didn't change the fact that it only created the object in memory, but did not actually draw it.  I changed it and played with it.  In addition, I set up a coordinate system placing (0, 0) at the center and that didn't draw the window either.

Comment: @lhoernle I think I fixed your problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see your circle because:

1. The radius of your circle (0.5) is too small
2. You placed the *center* of this small circle at (0, 0), which is at the top left corner
3. Your class's initializer was mispelled **inti**, hence the code was not called when you created your object.

Here is code that works:

```
from graphics import *

class Tracker:

    def __init__(self):
        # Window of size 500 x 500
        self.win = GraphWin('tracker', 500, 500)
        # Circle of radius 10 centered at (250, 250)            
        self.circle = Circle(Point(250, 250), 10)                                         
        self.circle.draw(self.win)
        self.win.getMouse()  # Pause to view result
        self.win.close()


def main():
    tracker = Tracker()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Where **graphics.py** is presumably taken from this [link](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py).

I modified the sample code from the above link (which is probably also what you did) to call `getMouse()` to keep the window around.

The result is

[image: this window]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I had set a coordinate system (self.win.setCoords(-10, -10, 10, 10)) when I was using the radius of 0.5 centered at (0, 0).  When I typed it into stackoverflow I forgot to add that.  I got it working now.  Thanks again.